# Java NullPointer Exception within for loop using ArrayQueue

Tags: java, arrays, loops, queue

so I have this code that for some reason constantly gives me a NullPointerError when I try to run it in a for loop over 1000 iterations, however it works perfectly fine when run once or under 1000 times.

The loop is as follows:

```
    double count = 0;
    Forest f;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        f = new Forest(20, 20, p);
        if (f.breadthFirstSearch())
            count++;
    }
```

Where Forest is simply creates and populates a random 2d array with ints of 0 and 1, where p is the probability of each cell being 0 or 1 to start. The breadthFirstSearch (and the Cell class it uses) code is this, where forestGrid is a 2d array of ints:

```
    public boolean breadthFirstSearch() {
    Queue<Cell> cellsToExplore = new ArrayQueue<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        if (forestGrid[0][i] == 1)
            cellsToExplore.enqueue(new Cell(0, i));

    while (!cellsToExplore.isEmpty())
    {
        Cell currentCell = cellsToExplore.dequeue();
        currentCell.setBurning(true);

        int currentRow = currentCell.getRow();
        int currentColumn = currentCell.getColumn();

        forestGrid[currentRow][currentColumn] = 2;

        if (currentRow == height-1)
            return true;

        if (forestGrid[currentRow+1][currentColumn] == 1)
            cellsToExplore.enqueue(new Cell(currentRow+1, currentColumn));

        if ((currentRow > 0)&&(forestGrid[currentRow-1][currentColumn] == 1))
            cellsToExplore.enqueue(new Cell(currentRow-1, currentColumn));

        if ((currentColumn < width-1)&&(forestGrid[currentRow][currentColumn+1] == 1))
            cellsToExplore.enqueue(new Cell(currentRow, currentColumn+1));

        if (((currentColumn > 0)&&forestGrid[currentRow][currentColumn-1] == 1))
            cellsToExplore.enqueue(new Cell(currentRow, currentColumn-1));
    }

    return false;
}

private static class Cell {

    boolean burning;
    int row, column;

    public Cell(int r, int c) {
        row = r;
        column = c;
        burning = false;
    }

    public boolean isBurning() {
        return burning;
    }

    public void setBurning(boolean b) {
        burning = b;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return column;
    }
}
```

and my ArrayQueue is this:

```
public static final int CAPACITY = 1000;
private E[] data;
private int f = 0;
private int size = 0;

public ArrayQueue() {
    this(CAPACITY);
}

public ArrayQueue(int capacity) {
    data = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

public void enqueue(E e) throws IllegalStateException {
    if (size == data.length)
        resize();

    int rear = (f + size) % data.length;
    data[rear] = e;
    size++;
}

public E dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    E answer = data[f];
    data[f] = null;
    f = (f + 1) % data.length;
    size--;

    return answer;
}

public E first() {
    if (isEmpty())
        return null;

    return data[f];
}

private void resize() {
    E[] temp = (E[]) new Object[data.length * 2];
    // System.out.println("Resizing array to " + temp.length + ".");
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        temp[i] = data[i];
    data = temp;
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
    int k = f;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i > 0)
            sb.append(", ");

        sb.append(data[k]);
        k = (k + 1) % data.length;
    }
    sb.append(")");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

As far as I can tell, there shouldn't be any issues, and I'm at my wit's end trying to get this to work. For some reason it always will eventually return null in breathFirstSearch at

```
    Cell currentCell = cellsToExplore.dequeue();
```

Here's the exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at algorithms.Forest.breadthFirstSearch(Forest.java:71)
at driver.FireProbability.computeProbabilty(FireProbability.java:18)
at driver.FireProbability.highestProbability(FireProbability.java:34)
at driver.FireProbability.main(FireProbability.java:8)
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace ?

Comment: @jr593 Sure, just added it. It points to "Cell currentCell = cellsToExplore.dequeue();" as the error, probably because the previous line is returning null for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
E answer = data[f];
data[f] = null;
```

`answer` points to the same place as `data[f]` Therefore, when you null `data[f]` you null the location pointed to by `answer`, and this gets returned.

Comment: Well since I'm saving the element in data[f] to answer, it shouldn't matter what happens in the array with answer. Either way, I figured it out - it was my resize method that caused my pointers to point at the wrong place.